# javascript RegExp to check for svg HTML tags for some weird reason is testing for true for "img" how is this happening?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, svg

For hours I was trying to figure out why image tags were not rendering and I couldn't figure it out. But after checking the `__proto__` on one of the images in Chrome dev tools I realized some how the below Regex was testing true for for img tags.

```
const isSVG = new RegExp(/(circle|clipPath|defs|ellipse|g|line|linearGradient|mask|path|pattern|polygon|polyline|radialGradient|rect|stop|svg|text|tspan)/i);
```

Since svg need to be created with creatElementNS I used the above RegExp object to test tags like `isSVG.test(node.type)`
but some how `img` was testing true.

How did that happen?

Comment: Is there some reason not to just do `['circle', 'clippath', ...].indexOf(node.type.toLowerCase()) !== -1`? But more basically, why are you doing this? You seem to already have the node in `node`. You want to create another node with the same tag? Or can't you just check `Element.namespaceURI`?

Comment: @torazaburo, I don't think they've got the node yet. `type` is not an default property of `Node`. I'll guess `node` is an custom object. But I agree regex here looks so weird, the Array solution seems way cleaner, even though still prone to error, and storing an `namespaceURI` prop in this custom `node` object would probably be the cleanest.

Comment: There's a `g` in `img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex includes the option `g`, which is included in `"img"`. If you want it to match the target string exactly, prefix with `^` and suffix with `$`, like this:

```
/^(circle|clipPath|defs|ellipse|g|line|linearGradient|mask|path|pattern|polygon|polyline|radialGradient|rect|stop|svg|text|tspan)$/i
```

Comment: ohhh, no wonder! I can't believe I missed that, but I guess my brain is a little scrambled from hours of debugging. Thanks!